# HttpUrl queryParameters into MultiValuedMap<String, String>

Tags: java, okhttp

I am trying to populate the query params of HttpUrl into MultiValuedMap.

I have been able to convert to a Map. Is there a way to convert the Map> into the desired MultiValuedMap?

```
    HttpUrl url = request.url();
    Map<String, List<String>> queryParams =
        request.url().queryParameterNames().stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(name -> name, name -> url.queryParameterValues(name)));
```

Answer (score 3):

`MultiValueMap` can be easily constructed as below

```
HttpUrl url = request.url();
MultiValueMap<String, List<String>> queryParams = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
request.url().queryParameterNames().stream()
                   .forEach(name -> queryParams.add(name, url.queryParameterValues(name)));
```

The `Map` values can be directly converted into `MultiValueMap` as below

```
MultiValueMap<String, List<String>> multiValueMap = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>(queryParams);
```

Comment: I need the MultivaluedMap of javax and not the one from the Springframework.

Comment: @user2761431 as you have not mentioned the package and the says `java` and `okhttp` tags, I interpreted it as `org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap`